# How can I display on screen with web3 the error message of the require function?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to show the error message of the solidity require() function in my website, do you know if web3 has some function to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Solidity require() statement does not return an error message per se, since it aborts the operation you will need to implement a [try/catch block](https://blog.ethereum.org/2020/01/29/solidity-0.6-try-catch/)" inside the smart contract as seen here:

```
contract A {
event E(string msg);

function e() public {
    require(false, "BUM!");
    emit E("hello");
}
}

contract Test {
  A a = new A();

  event E(bytes data);

  function test() public {
    (bool res, bytes memory returnData) = address(a).call(abi.encode(A.e.selector));
    try A.e.selector
    {
        //What it does if no error happens...
    }
    catch (bytes memory reason) {
        emit E(reason);
    }
  }
}
```

Here `emit E(reason);` will emit the error message so you can display it if you have an event listener, or you can choose to return the string and display that from the transaction call, but I didn't proposed that because I don't know if your function call already returns a string.

Comment: And how I integrate it with web3?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap function call in try-catch on javascript.

```
async function claimAirdropSupportingFee(){
  let fee = await instance.idoContract.methods.airdropFee.call().call();
  try{
     let transaction = await instance.idoContract.methods.claimPassiveAirdrop().send({shouldPollResponse: false, feeLimit: 50000000, value: fee, from: _account});
     notify.success("Request submitted succesfully");
  }catch(error){
     console.log(error);
     notify.error(error);
  }
 }
```

If the function call fails with `require`, it'll be caught in catch block in `error` object. Further you can query `error` object to grab that `require` text.